# Calculate payments on a month by month bases from date opened SQL 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, common-table-expression

I'm currently trying to replicate an old report that used to produce a rolling sum of collections. However it wasn't a standard month on month. Here is screen shot of the excel based report.

[image]

The blue section is based on a simple query and gives the dataset used to start(EXAMPLE):

```
SELECT COUNT(AccountNo) AS Number, SUM(Balance) AS Value, DATENAME(MM,DateOpened) AS Month, DATEPART(Y,DateOpened) AS Year FROM tblAccounts
GROUP BY DATENAME(MM,DateOpened), DATEPART(Y,DateOpened)
```

The tables are very basic :

```
AccountNo | Balance | DateOpened
12345     | 1245.55 | 01/01/2015
```

I'm struggling to get it to work out the months on a rolling basis, so Month 1 for Apr 2011 will be the first month for those files (payments in April), month 2 would be payments in May for the accounts opened in April (I hope that is clear).

So this means Month 1 for April would be April, and Month 1 for Nov would be Nov. Payments are stored in a table tblPayments

```
AccountNo | DatePayment | PaymentValue
12345     | 02/02/2015  | 15.99
```

Please ask if I haven't been clear enough

Comment: Could you provide with source table from which data has to be fetched and desired output

Comment: Added in the table structures. They are very basic tables @SarathAvanavu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have a column called "DatePayment", you should simply do something like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(AccountNo) AS Number, SUM(Balance) AS Value, 
    DATENAME(MM,DateOpened) AS Month, DATEPART(Y,DateOpened) AS Year,
    DATEDIFF(MONTH, DateOpened, DatePayment) AS MonthN
FROM [...]
GROUP BY DATENAME(MM,DateOpened), DATEPART(Y,DateOpened), 
    DATEDIFF(MONTH, DateOpened, DatePayment)
```

The DATEDIFF simply counts the months between the date the account was opened and the date of the payment. Note that you might want to change the DateOpened to always be the 1st of the month in the DATEDIFF calculation.

In the `FROM [...]` part of your query, you will need a join between your Payments-table and the table holding your accounts, in order to be able to compare `DateOpened` with `DatePayment`. You should join them on the AccountNo-column. This looks something like this:

```
FROM Accounts INNER JOIN Payments ON Accounts.AccountNo = Payments.AccountNo
```

After doing this, you will need to make sure that all references to columns that exist in both tables are fully qualified. This means that `COUNT(AccountNo)` should be changed to `COUNT(Accounts.AccountNo)`, etc.

Comment: Thanks, I'm struggling to see how this would get me the column range needed (1-24) as with the previous report. @Dan

Comment: Well, the new column `MonthN` outputs a number from 0 to N (depending on the number of months between the payment and the opening). If you add 1 to this value and prefix it with "Month ", then you have your column headers. If you want the SQL Server to Pivot the data for you, look into the `PIVOT` keyword. But if you use the output of my query suggestion in a report, you should be able to create column groups that group on the "MonthN" columns, without pivoting the data.

Comment: Thank to your answer I've got this running however I need to force it to recognize that the same month is month 1 in the datediff, right now i get Month 0? @Dan

Comment: Simply add +1 in the `SELECT`-part of your query like this: `DATEDIFF(MONTH, DateOpened, DatePayment) + 1 AS MonthN`